# Need Help regarding OSPF and RIP in NS2

Tags: networking, ns2

I need TCL Script for implementation of OSPF and RIP in NS2 or someone tell me how to implement OSPF patch in NS2 I have installed NS2 using cygwin in windows...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OSPF patch : `ospf_ns235.patch` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbjctSHF5TWduVFU/view?usp=sharing

The examples are included in the patch :

```
ns-2.35/tcl/ex/{ ospf0.tcl, ospf2.tcl, ospf3.tcl  ......  ospf9.tcl }
```

The original ns-2.34 patches https://sourceforge.net/projects/ospf4ns/files/ospf4ns2.34/

Cygwin, suggest : `cd ns-2.35/ && patch -p1 < ospf_ns235.patch`

Comment: Sir Could you please elaborate the commands for installing this patch as i have installed ns 2 via cygwin in windows 7 ...

Comment: $ patch -p0 < ospf_ns235.patch
patching file ns-2.35/classifier/classifier-mtopology.cc
patching file ns-2.35/classifier/classifier-mtopology.h
can't find file to patch at input line 95
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -Naur ns-2.35-orig/common/agent.cc ns-2.35/common/agent.cc
|--- ns-2.35-orig/common/agent.cc       2010-03-08 06:54:49.000000000 +0100
|+++ ns-2.35/common/agent.cc    2015-01-24 16:57:49.539072615 +0100
--------------------------
File to patch: